# JS: Expanding div, IE problems

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I recently fixed a prob I had with the sliding field thanks to you so I wanted to ask this problem too.

On the site: http://www.trulyscience.com/test/index.html I have a little box with questions. It slides open when you press it and slides shut when your press again. 
Now my problem is that this does not work in IE.

Here is the code:

```
function loadQuestion(){

var lol;
lol = 1;

jQuery('#question').click(function(){
    if (lol==0){
      jQuery('#question').animate({height:'300'});
      lol = 1;
    }else{
      jQuery('#question').animate({height:'30'});
      lol = 0;                     
    }
});

jQuery('#question').trigger('click'); // Simulating click
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
loadQuestion();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a problem with calling loadQuestion() before the question div is available to jQuery, so the click event is never added.

I added a breakpoint and a watch in the ready function which seemed to indicate this at least.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // does this print 0 in IE? 
    console.log(jQuery('#question').length);

    loadQuestion();
});​
```

Just to verify you could move the script to the bottom of the page and see if that solves the problem. If it does, I would still investigate why the question div is not available when document ready triggers in IE.

Comment: It doesn't do anything either, really odd O.o

Comment: It works for me now, after you moved the code block to the bottom of the page.

Comment: I put that code in now and it doesn't do anything. I'm also getting errors: Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Sat, 18 Aug 2012 22:49:03 UTC


Message: Invalid character
Line: 157
Char: 4
Code: 0
URI: http://www.trulyscience.com/test/index.html


Message: 'console' is undefined
Line: 124
Char: 9
Code: 0
URI: http://www.trulyscience.com/test/index.html

Comment: ok, didn't realise you were using IE8 which doesn't have native support for console. Change "console.log" to "alert" instead. You should see an alert box with the value of 1, which means the question div is found or 0 if it's not found. When the script is at the bottom it should be found.

Comment: I'm trying to make the site compatible for all browsers, and as usual IE is the only problem. (Hate the browser so much)
Still nothing though, I got the change up and don't see any 1's or 0's.

Comment: at the very end of ready script block, you seem to have some strange invisible characters at the end of the line }); Can you delete all whitespace at the end of that line and try again?

Comment: It is like this now:

`<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // does this print 0 in IE? 
    alert(jQuery('#question').length);
    loadQuestion();
 });​
</script>`

Still nothing =/

Comment: you still have a strange character (which is invisible unless you paste the code into an editor which shows control characters etc.). It's been removed in this code: `<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    loadQuestion();
 });
</script>`

Comment: Copypasted that and still nothing in either IE as FF. Here is my sourcecode http://pastebin.com/YbFiUfak It is a bit messy but the start and end are what matter (I think) and those are readable :P

I'm either doing something something close to being retarded or there is something wrong with my host server.

Comment: now you have a <script type="text/javascript"> too many at the very bottom, but other than that it should work now. Please note that in my code I removed the alert box, so you won't get that. But the expanding of the question should work now.

Comment: Still nothing xD It is nagging about not knowing what console is on line 124: `console.log(e.target.tagName);` in the expand/collapse code. I assume that I can't name that alert, what should I rename it as? (This is probably the retarded problem that I failed to see for too long)

Comment: you can remove that line, console.log is only used for debugging/logging, and it's not supported in IE8, so you get an error. It has nothing to do with the functionality of your expand/collapse. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Works great now! Thanks for bearing with me, I know that I can be slow :P (quite new to JS) 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadQuestion(){

var lol;
lol = 1;
var invalidElems = {
    INPUT : true,
    TEXTAREA : true
};
jQuery('#question').click(function(e){
    if(e.target.tagName in invalidElems === false){
        if (lol==0){
          jQuery('#question').animate({height:'300'});
          lol = 1;
        }else{
          jQuery('#question').animate({height:'30'});
          lol = 0;                     
        }
    }
});

jQuery('#question').trigger('click'); // Simulating click
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
loadQuestion();
});​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tJugd/1059/)

Comment: That solved one of my problems, but it still does nothing in IE. I really hate that browser -_-